# Javascript Fetch is Slow (60ms vs 3ms)

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Running Javascript [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) takes about 60ms per call on my machine. Compared to Python [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) at 3ms, this is much slower.

## Questions

- Why is `fetch` so much slower?
- Is there any way to speed it up? I am OK with answers that require me to reconfigure my browser.

---

## Experiment

These are the details of my experiment.

### System

- Browser: Firefox 74.0 (64-bit)
- Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
- Server: Django 3.0.3 (but since `requests` is much faster, this should not matter). Server and client are on the same machine.
- For `requests`: Python 3.7.6 with `requests` 2.23.0
- Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6600K CPU @ 3.50GHz

### Javascript Fetch

HTML that runs the Javascript below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript that makes multiple `fetch` requests and reports the average time per request.

```
// record all times
const times = [];

function call() {
    // record starting time
    const startFetch = performance.now();
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/timer/time")
        .then((response) => {
            // compute fetch duration
            const elapsedFetch = performance.now() - startFetch;

            // record result
            console.log(elapsedFetch);
            times.push(elapsedFetch);

            if (times.length<100) {
                // start next call
                call();
            } else {
                // report statistics
                const totalFetch = times.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
                const averageFetch = totalFetch/times.length;
                const standardDeviation = Math.sqrt(times.reduce((a, b) => a + (b-averageFetch) ** 2, 0)/times.length);
                const totalElapsed = performance.now() - startTime;
                console.log("Average fetch time:", averageFetch, '+-', standardDeviation);
                console.log("Percentage of overall elapsed:", totalFetch/totalElapsed)
            }
        });
}

var startTime = performance.now();
call();
```

Firefox console output when visiting the HTML page:

```
Average fetch time: 62.51 +- 31.450117646838777
Percentage of overall elapsed: 0.9993605115907274
```

Similar result for Google Chrome Version 80.0.3987.149 (Official Build) (64-bit)

```
Average fetch time: 49.93 +- 4.92596183501253
Percentage of overall elapsed: 0.9993995196156925
```

Using [XMLHttpRequest](https://javascript.info/xmlhttprequest) instead of `fetch`:

```
xhr.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:8000/timer/time");
xhr.send();
xhr.onload = ...
```

yields similar results:

```
Average fetch time: 60.19 +- 26.325157169521326
Percentage of overall elapsed: 0.9993358791300017
```

### Python requests

Code analogous to Javascript, but in Python:

```py
import requests
import time
import numpy as np

times = []
start_time = time.time()

for i in range(100):
    start_get = time.time()
    response = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/timer/time')
    elapsed_get = time.time() - start_get
    times += [elapsed_get]

total_elapsed = time.time() - start_time

total_get = np.sum(times)
average_get = np.average(times)
standard_deviation = np.std(times)

print("Average get time:", average_get, '+-', standard_deviation)
print("Percentage of overall elapsed:", total_get/total_elapsed)
```

Output:

```
Average get time: 0.0025661182403564453 +- 0.0001961814487345112
Percentage of overall elapsed: 0.9994576986364464
```

Comment: I think that fetch maps your received data not really sure but it may be the reason. Did you try xmlhttprequest basic request speed?

Comment: You're comparing the browser implementation of request  to a python module - it's not comparable (apples and oranges). A better comparison would be `fetch` vs `xhttprequest`

Comment: @DenisTsoi That *is* what he wants to compare though....

Comment: As @BenBeri said, `fetch` does a lot more work that python `request`, think about it `fetch` is in the brower so it needs to think about `cross origin`, security, cookies, etc. Then save the output in a safe way, whereas python `request` doesn't have to care about all that out of the box.

Comment: @Peter You should use `performance.now()` instead for your timers.  Also keep in mind that as a mitigation against some side-channel attacks and fingerprinting, all of these JavaScript timings are potentially off.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now  Can you elaborate on your use case?  I'm guessing you're trying to synchronize a clock or something... perhaps start with an existing connection via Server-Sent Events/EventSource or Web Socket.

Comment: More importantly, why does this even matter?

Comment: @BenBeri xmlhttprequest gives roughly the same result as fetch (see update above).

Comment: @Brad thanks for the hint. I switched to `performance.now()` (see update above), but it did not really affect my results.

Comment: Also... keep in mind that `fetch` resolves as soon as the response starts, not when it is finished.

Comment: @Brad Regarding my use case: I need to quickly update the client with timing and other information, every ~10ms. The high server load of polling is not an issue in my case (long story), so I am/was hoping there might be a simple way to speed up `fetch`, given that `requests` is so much faster.

Comment: @Peter Unfortunately, the timing client-side isn't even that fast, and it's only gotten worse thanks to all of this security crap in the last year.  :-(  The closest you can get is `requestAnimationFrame()`, and on a good day that tops out at 60 FPS... ~16.6667 ms.  You should post a new question with your *full use case* and perhaps we can suggest alternatives for what you're doing.  An entirely different approach is needed.

Comment: @Brad ok, thanks for the hint. And yes, my use case deserves a separate question - it would side-track this question too much. The answer to this question seems to be "browsers do more work, so there is no hope to get significantly below 60ms".

Comment: @Peter I don't think that's an accurate portrayal of what's going on here.  Frankly, what you're attempting to do is a flawed approach anyway.  If you need to update something every 10 milliseconds, making a new HTTP request (and potentially a new TCP connection) each time is the wrong way to do it.  And, we can't suggest the right way with no information about what it is you're doing anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I still don't really know why Javascript fetch is so slow, I have been able to switch to a faster option:

I now use [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) (on the client) and [Django Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (on the server), which are significantly faster.